# Sub state-machine as inital active state in boost::msm

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, state-machine, c++98, boost-msm

I want a sub state-machine to be the "initial_state" of a state-machine. The following should be a broken down version of the code.

```
struct E {
};

struct A : public boost::msm::front::state<> {
    template <class TEvent, class TStateMachine>
    void on_entry(TEvent const& event, TStateMachine& stateMachine) {  
    }

    template <class TEvent, class TStateMachine>
    void on_exit(TEvent const& event, TStateMachine& stateMachine) {  
    }
};

struct B: public boost::msm::front::state<> {
    template <class TStateMachine>
    void on_entry(E const& event, TStateMachine& stateMachine) {  
    }

    template <class TStateMachine>
    void on_exit(E const& event, TStateMachine& stateMachine) {  
    }
};

struct SubMachineDefinition : public boost::msm::front::state_machine_def<SubMachineDefinition> {
    typedef boost::msm::front::state_machine_def<SubMachineDefinition> Base;

    typedef A initial_state;

    struct transition_table : boost::mpl::vector<
        typename Base::template _row<A, E, B>
    > {};

    // Added via suggestion of sehe
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_entry(IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

    // Added via suggestion of sehe
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_exit (IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
};

struct SuperMachineDefinition : public boost::msm::front::state_machine_def<SuperMachineDefinition > {
    typedef SubMachineDefinition initial_state;

    struct transition_table : boost::mpl::vector<> {};
};

int main() {
    boost::msm::back::state_machine<SuperMachineDefinition> states;
    states.start();
    states.process_event(E()); // This crashes
}
```

While this compiles fine, when I call `process_event`, it crashes. Is this even possible or is there a way of debugging this?

### **EDIT 1:**

I now set a breakpoint on `A::on_entry`. When `start` gets called, it does not break, so my obvious question - why is the sub state-machine not used!?

### **EDIT 2:**

Interestingly, when I replace `SubMachineDefinition` with `boost::msm::back::state_machine<SubMachineDefinition>` (as `initial_state`) I get a compilation error, stating it tries to call `B::on_entry` with `InitEvent` instead of `E`. I am by now **very** confused.

### **EDIT 3:**

Actually I did copy the wrong overloads for `A`. I also did apply sehe's `SubMachineDefinition::on_entry` and `SubMachineDefinition::on_exit` definitions. Still, I get the compilation error, that it tries to call `B::on_entry` with `InitEvent`.

Comment: You're already confused. Now I don't want to ruin your 2222 rep... Maybe if you get another 7 bronze badges. That would be leet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already noted, you need to make the `SubMachine` state a *backend*

```
typedef boost::msm::back::state_machine<SubMachineDefinition> SubMachine;
typedef SubMachine initial_state;
```

Next, you need to be prepared to handle (or ignore) the `InitEvent` which is present so the `SubMachine` can know what made it enter the initial state.

The simplest, and typical, way to do this is to just template the event argument:

```
struct A : public boost::msm::front::state<> {
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_entry(IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_exit (IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
};
```

But of course, you can use overloading as over to handle certain events explicitly:

```
struct A : public boost::msm::front::state<> {
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_entry(IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
    template <class SM> void on_entry(E const&, SM&)            { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_exit (IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
};
```

You may be tempted to write it like

```
template <class SM> void on_entry(typename SM::InitEvent const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
```

That would indeed work, if not for the sub-state-machine. This is because the InitEvent is actually a `msm::state_machine<SuperMachineDefinition>::InitEvent`, and not a  `msm::state_machine<SubMachineDefinition>::InitEvent`. You can do a load of template-magic to detect the InitEvent explicitly, but you should probably just use overloading as shown.

---

#### **UPDATE** In response to the comments:

> **Q**.  *It would be seriously great if someone could explain to me, how the implementation searches for the state it calls InitEvent on*

- The point is that it /doesn't/ search for a specific state to run that on; it uses the *visitor pattern* to do this, which implies that statically, all sub-states must be prepared to accept the `InitEvent`.

  The runtime log shows that only `A::on_entry(InitEvent const&, SM&)` is invoked. 
  You can simply "eat" the `InitEvent`. (See above, about using overloads).

  In the end it comes down to *separation of concerns*: the sub-machine is an opaque state as seen from the super machine. [The same limitation is mentioned in the documentation **(#limitation-submachine)**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s02.html#limitation-submachine) with respect to event properties:

  > *There is, however, a limitation for submachines. If a submachine's substate has an entry action which requires a special event property (like a given method), the compiler will require all events entering this submachine to support this property.*

  Of course to handle InitEvent you don't *need* to do SFINAE wizardry, as you can just overload on the types of events that you do expect.

> **Q**. *Can you please have a look at your struct `B`, why is it not using `E`? That's the reason (cheat), why your example works*

- It's not a cheat. Your code was simply not satisfying the requirements on submachine state `on_entry` methods.

  Now that you have recognized the particular element that causes the problem in your code, it's probably wise to accept this as the path to your solution...

---

Fully working example **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e912c1e92ae91d8)**

```
#include <boost/msm/msm_grammar.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct E {
};

struct A : public boost::msm::front::state<> {
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_entry(IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
    template <class SM> void on_entry(E const&, SM&)            { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_exit (IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
};

struct B : public boost::msm::front::state<> {
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_entry(IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_exit (IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
};

struct SubMachineDefinition : public boost::msm::front::state_machine_def<SubMachineDefinition>
{
    typedef boost::msm::front::state_machine_def<SubMachineDefinition> Base;

    typedef A initial_state;

    struct transition_table : boost::mpl::vector<
        typename Base::template _row<A, E, B>,
        typename Base::template _row<B, E, A>
    > {};

    template <class IE, class SM> void on_entry(IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
    template <class IE, class SM> void on_exit (IE const&, SM&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } 
};

struct SuperMachineDefinition : public boost::msm::front::state_machine_def<SuperMachineDefinition > {
    typedef boost::msm::back::state_machine<SubMachineDefinition> SubMachine;
    typedef SubMachine initial_state;

    struct transition_table : boost::mpl::vector<> {};
};

int main() {
    boost::msm::back::state_machine<SuperMachineDefinition> states;
    states.start();
    states.process_event(E());
    states.process_event(E());
    states.process_event(E());
    states.process_event(E());
    states.process_event(E());
}
```

Comment: I still have the problem, that the wrong overload of `B::on_entry` is used. It would be seriously great if someone could explain to me, how the implementation searches for the state it calls InitEvent on.

Comment: Can you please have a look at your `struct B`, why is it not using `E`!? That's the reason (cheat), why your example works.

Comment: I'm in a meeting. Is not a cheat if you use a framework as it's designed :) I've a comment pending on my desktop. Patience  :)

Comment: @abergmeier I've addressed your complaints in the answer under **UPDATE** (it was too large for a comment). If you're really unhappy about how submachines work in MSM, perhaps you can start a discussion at the Boost mailing list.

Comment: I forget to mention in my answer, that you can prevent the "unintuitive" `on_entry` overloads if you just... don't rely on these _generic_ hooks, and instead use transition actions. (The docs **[seem a bit out of date](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s02.html#d0e1209)** on whether you get a reference to the SM in your action method)